# Ordering fields inside Inlines in Django Admin

Tags: django, admin

I have a ManyToMany relationship setup with intermediary objects in Django. Any ideas how I can order the < select >s in the Inlines that show up for the intermediary objects?

Answer (score 8):

You can use `fields` inside an `InlineModelAdmin`:

```
class FooInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Foo
    fields = ('field1', 'field2', 'field3')
```

Comment: Sorry, but I wanted to order the elements that show up under a FK relationship in the intermediary object. The word < select > was eaten up by SO.

Answer (score 2):

I think this could be what you're looking for:

*Orderable inlines using drag and drop with jQuery UI* 
http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1053/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried specifying a model for the many-to-many relationship using the `through` argument? You should be able to customize the admin with a `ModelAdmin` class then.

```
class A(models.Model):
      pass

class B(models.Model):
   m2m = models.ManyToManyField(A, through='C')

class C(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
    b = models.ForeignKey(B)
```